# Jquery validation stopped working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, forms

here's my call to the validate function. Everything works fine with this code.

```
$('#createForm').validate(function () {
});
```

But when I try to modify it a bit, the whole validation stop working:

```
$('#createForm').validate(function () {
               errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 error.insertAfter(element);
               },
               debug:true

            });
```

Any Idea?

Comment: just remove `function ()` in `.validate(function () {` and that should  work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you shouldn't have **function()** in there.  change it to:

```
$('#createForm').validate(
    {
         errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 error.insertAfter(element);
         },
         debug:true

      }
);
```

the stuff in the { } is the options. it's not a function :)

Answer (score 2):

just remove `function ()` in `.validate(function () {` and that should  work...